# What's the correct way to connect pages of my website?

Tags: asp.net

I'm just starting web-developing now (I do have experience with C#). And I've seen a recommendation to use `Web.sitemap` to have a list of pages of my website. Does this help? Will I be able to use this *instead* of having links on my web pages somehow? And what about being accessible to Google so my website will be found by searchers – will this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web.sitemap is not primarily a control to be used for your main navigation; it's meant as a navigational overview for the user and is typically only needed in large sites. It doesn't affect your SEO in any way - Google is more interested in the quality of your content.

A site map (NOT a Web.sitemap) is a list of pages on your site, and used in conjunction with a robots.txt file, CAN help your SEO. You can use the following tool to generate a site map automatically (although you'll nearly always have to hand tweak it as well):

http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

The normal way to build navigation for a small/medium site is to create a set of links as an unordered set (ul/li) and style them with CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. (I thought Web.sitemap _was_  site map.)

Comment: "The normal way to build navigation ..." – do you mean there's some way to have this automatically add hyperlinks on each page? Or is there no way to eliminate the need to add links on pages?

Comment: You don't want to go there unless your site is enterprise-sized! I would suggest using master pages with your menu(s) created as user controls :)

Comment: Uh, beginner here. Just making sure – This is not instead of links on pages. Only as shortcuts – a general map of the site. Right?

Comment: Your menus can be part of the master pages, in the gutter - they don't actually have to be part of your pages. And even if they did, that's not a big deal to implement :)

Comment: Sitemap is a general map of site, yes. You NEED proper navigation for your site - menus are just a list of links. Don't create a site without proper navigational menus.

Comment: Thanks. you've been a lot of help.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use Web.Sitemap as navigation source, though probably not recommended.  I've used Web.sitemap driven navigation for a couple of sites I've developed.  However, it really only works well if you have a simple site with static content pages.  Here's the code I used for example:

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="MainMenuDataSource" runat="server"
    ShowStartingNode="false" StartingNodeOffset="0"
    StartFromCurrentNode="false" />

<ul id="jsddm" style="padding-top:10px;">
    <asp:Repeater ID="MainMenuRepeater" DataSourceID="MainMenuDataSource" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li><a href="<%#Container.DataItem.Url%>"><%#Container.DataItem.Title%></a>
                <ul>
            <asp:Repeater ID="MainMenuRepeater_2" DataSource='<%# Container.DataItem.ChildNodes %>' runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Utilities.GetSecondaryMenuItem(Container.DataItem, False)%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

Where `Utilities.GetSecondaryMenuItem` is just a helper function in our application that uses custom attributes from the sitemap nodes to control the display formatting of the secondary menu.

Answer (score 0):

Links are a fundamental part of any website and there's no reason to avoid them.

A sitemap is just an XML file that defines the site structure, and it's used mainly by search engines to index sites. You can use them for other things too, like crumb trails for example, but they are not a substitute for hyperlinks.